# EditText in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm trying to have a button in a fragment increment a textfield when clicked I can do this not problem if I'm not using a fragment but I cannot get it to work in the fragment.

I've created a very basic test app to work with.

The t1 is supposed to set the value to numOfClicks but in debugging the t1 value is always null.

```
  private int numOfClicks;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container,false);

    Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button2 =(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);


   // EditText t1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked);
   // t1.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            //button code here
           //toast statement works!
           //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            EditText t1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked);
            numOfClicks++;
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(numOfClicks));


            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Toast.makeText((v.getContext()), "button 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: just remove v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked) from onClick make it onCreateView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare EditText globally:

```
EditText t1 ;
```

Initialize in onCreateView():

```
t1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked);
```

Set text in onClick():

```
t1.setText(Integer.toString(numOfClicks));
```

Comment: You're welcom. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should declare an editText in the page1.xml named numClicked. Then you can try this code :

{

```
private int numOfClicks;
private EditText t1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false);

    Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);


    t1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            //button code here
            //toast statement works!
            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            numOfClicks++;
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(numOfClicks));


            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Toast.makeText((v.getContext()), "button 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Not do this.. Why**?

- The parameter View is view of you button that has been onClick(touch on screen). This view has no other components inside it, only herself.

Detail: **EditText t1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked);**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                //button code here
               //toast statement works!
               //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                EditText t1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked);
                numOfClicks++;
                t1.setText(Integer.toString(numOfClicks));


                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                Toast.makeText((v.getContext()), "button 2 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

**What Do?**

- Find your component reference in **onViewCreated event**. But why? 
  onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState), **view parameter is referente "main" view, she have all your components of this layout.**

  ```
  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
      t1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numClicked);
  }
  ```
- **Dont forgot**: You need create a class atribute, type EditText with name t1 to run this example.

Answer (score 0):

Your numOfClicks not have value in start you only declaration not set value.

steps your program:

1. numOfClicks = null:
2. numOfClicks++ ( null +1) = null

so answer is set value for numOfClicks =0;

Answer (score 0):

The View `v` in `onClick()` you are calling `.findViewByID` on is actually the button that was clicked (which is also a view)

So to find the text field you need to find the view by the activity. Which you should be able to get by calling v`.getParrent()` unless the button is inside a container that is different from the EditText

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
Then you can declare it as:
 `@BindView(R.id.numClicked) EditText text;`

Also declare `int numOfClicks = 0;` so it has a value from the start.

And also set the listener like this:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn1)
public void submit(View view) {
    numOfClicks++;
        text.setText(Integer.toString(numOfClicks));
}
```

And then in your OnCreate you only have this:
`ButterKnife.bind(this);`

This is better than normal findViewByID, because the views are create on compilation, and are injected automatically inside the Activity, at onCreate, being way more efficient than your standard initialization. Also like this, the views are declared global, so you can use them anywhere from the Activity